Migrating react native ios project from Objective-C to Swift
I have been trying to migrate the ios project created by npx react-native init (which is Objective-C) to Swift.
I was following the document available at https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps to do the migration (in which it specified how to change a particular screen to render react native view in ios app). I am looking a way to update the AppDelegate file so that the initial view itself is rendered by RTC View.
I tried the solutins mentioned to the SO post React Native app purely in Swift, but it doesn't seem to work in the latest version (v0.73.6 at time of this post) of React Native.
This is my current AppDelegate.swift file:
import UIKit
import React

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    var bridge: RCTBridge!
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        /**
         * Loading JavaScript code - uncomment the one you want.
         *
         * OPTION 1
         * Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
         *
         * $ npm start
         *
         * To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer
         * (you can get this by typing `ifconfig` into the terminal and selecting the
         * `inet` value under `en0:`) and make sure your computer and iOS device are
         * on the same Wi-Fi network.
         */

        let jsCodeLocation = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true")

        /**
         * OPTION 2
         * Load from pre-bundled file on disk. The static bundle is automatically
         * generated by "Bundle React Native code and images" build step.
         */

        // jsCodeLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("main", withExtension: "jsbundle")

        let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL:(jsCodeLocation as URL?)!, moduleName: "test", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions:launchOptions)

        self.bridge = rootView.bridge

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let rootViewController = UIViewController()

        rootViewController.view = rootView

        self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
      }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }
}

And given below is the app structure:

The index.js file:
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>
        Test
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  }
});

// Module name
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => Main);

And the metro config:
const { getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig } = require('@react-native/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
const { assetExts, sourceExts } = defaultConfig.resolver;

/**
 * Metro configuration
 * https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/configuration
 *
 * @type {import('metro-config').MetroConfig}
 */

const config = {
  transformer: {
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve('react-native-svg-transformer'),
  },
  resolver: {
    assetExts: assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== 'svg'),
    sourceExts: [...sourceExts, 'svg'],
  },
};

module.exports = mergeConfig(defaultConfig, config);

On running npx react-native start (with target as ios), the app is launching to display a blank white screen.
One more observation is that on app launch, the build process is happening again.
What changes do I have to make inorder to get it running?
Thanks in advance.
